# ICBMs versus number of available warheads

Tags: icbm

ICBMs are known to be able to carry multiple warheads. The capability to launch against multiple targets in the same time is important when in an all-out war but I can imagine many times that a single strike may be tactically desirable.

So are there ICBMs (land or submarine based) loaded with a single warhead? Can an ICBM "unload" warheads relatively quickly according to tactical needs? Or are single nuclear strikes performed exclusively by air assets (bombers, cruise missiles)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about military technology and not space exploration.

Comment: OK, sorry for being off-topic. Any idea on where I could ask?

Comment: @Georgios I'm not aware of any SE site where it would fit. Unfortunately, it is not possible for there to be a Stack Exchange community for every topic. You can go to Area 51 and make a new proposal or support an existing one that might cover your question.

Answer (score 2):

Using an ICBM for a single strike is politically unlikely. The receiving state (esp. if it's a nuclear power) will assume incoming ICBM = the beginning of nuclear war and will launch its own missiles in retaliation, before they get annihiliated. 
So for a single strike, other methods are used.

There has been talk of building ICBMs with conventional explosives, but the above scenario keeps that from happening.

Comment: plus the "surgical strike" (against a target NOT in one of the global superpowers) would be probably conducted out of a submarine, with IRBM - or using a stealth bomber plane.

Comment: I had North Korea in mind when asking...

Comment: NK is next-door to China, which won't look kindly on ICBMs fired in their general direction.